# FragmentActivity with ViewPager managing multiple fragments taking 2 back presses to exit

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have tried searching across to find a solution for it, but none of them seemed to work.

My use case is: I have a FragmentActivity which contains a ViewPager to manager couple of fragments whose that if coming from different data sources - thus things like Service,Content Proviers,Loaders etc are involved.

While the onCreateView of my Fragments is only called once, but when I try to exit the application by pressing the back key, the view pager first removes the fragment set and display the blank activity, and the consequent press on the back actually exits the application.

I have tried couple of things like:

- calling `finish()` in onKey... onBackPressed within the activity
- calling `getActivity().finish()` from withing the Fragment and its
  main layout view
  but none of them worked.

**closing application by using its PID - thats something I dont want to try.

Its surely not the standard behaviour becuase I have seen people on SO asking the opposite of my query with their apps getting exited.

So, I would really like the activity to be closed on the first press of the back button.

Comment: When you add your fragments with a FragmentTransaction are you also calling addToBackstack()? Also it might be helpful if you post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: No,I'm not using FragmentTransactions, since I have the ViewPager , I'm creating the references of all the fragments and passing them as a List<Fragment> to the PagerAdapter and once the `getView`is called, I return the fragment from the List